# how to get the object id in azure web app using powershell command

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

I have enabled the identity in azure web app, it has created one object id. I want to pull the object id using PowerShell, like that I want to pull all the app service using powershell command

Comment: NOTE that your webapp may not yet have an id. you can check if you have an `object-id` or aka `principalId` by going to the webapp "overview" and at far right click "JSON view". scroll to bottom of json and see if you have an "identity" with the "princpalId". if you do not, first run this: `az webapp identity assign -n <your webapp> -g <your group>` _(which btw will output your new prinicpalId for use in objectid azure commands)_.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this command:

```
(Get-AzWebApp -Name <Your_WebApp_Name> -ResourceGroupName <Your_ResourceGroup>).Identity.PrincipalId
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer for this. I try to get my identity id in my webapp, so to get this using below command in PowerShell

Command:

```
az webapp identity show --name yourwebappname --resource-group resrourcegroupname --query principalId
```

Example:

```
az webapp identity show --name ph-prod-blue-portal --resource-group test_resource --query principalId
```

you will get the below result

```
"abc-def-ghi-ijk-lnmkop"
```

Answer (score 0):

- As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-view-managed-identity-service-principal-powershell#view-the-service-principal), we have alternate command to get the Azure WebApp Service Principal ID.

Display name must be your WebApp Name

```cs
 Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "Core52022"
```

[image]

- To check whether you got the correct ID, you can verify it in Azure Active Directory
  Navigate to the `Portal` => `Azure AD` => `Enterprise applications`,remove all the filters and in search box type your Web App name

[image]

Comment: I don't have an AD access and getting the error if I run the command in powershell (error: Get-AzADServicePrincipal : The term 'Get-AzADServicePrincipal' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,)